# Effect of running a batch filed as admin on included programs

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file, administrator

Windows 10. I have a batch file that contains a number of

```
start xyz
```

to start various programs. Some of those programs must be run in admin mode.

If I create a shortcut to a batch file and set the advanced properties of the shortcut to be run as administrator.
Will all the programs inside the batch file be executed as administrator? If not, is there a way to start a  program as an administrator from inside the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

> Will all the programs inside the batch file be executed as administrator?

**Yes**. Running a batch script as administrator also runs processes started by the script with admin rights.

Here's an experiment you can try if you'd like to verify it yourself. I verified this experimentally by trying it myself.

Here was my test, which uses `gpedit.msc`. If you try opening this *without* administrative rights, you will get an MMC warning and then a limited console window will open up. If you open it with admin rights, it opens normally.

1. I created a batch script that contained, simply, `start gpedit.msc`
2. I created a shortcut to the batch script
3. I changed the advanced properties to `Run As Administrator`

When executing the shortcut, a UAC prompt appears, authorizing the batch script to run with elevated privileges. Unsurprisingly, anything executed by the batch script also runs with administrative rights.